# Footer stuck middle of the page when zoom in| Bootsrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I just start to learn Bootstrap with HTML and CSS. With bootstrap grid system I create 3 sections like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq4hr.jpg). Everything is fine as long as you use >= medium screen.
The problem occurs when using one small screen (or you just zoom in), the content is bigger and the *height* longer. The footer end up middle of the screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT88f.jpg).

---

I tried:

- Set body height 100%
- clear both
- postion:absolute; bottom:0

  I think the cause is coming from the div in the menu. When zoom in, the content stretching but the footer don't recognize it

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Warnes&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500;700&display=swap');
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(/images/nick-karvounis-Ciqxn7FE4vE-unsplash.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
/* Navbar Start */
#brandName{
    font-family: 'Warnes', cursive;
    color: #FF511C;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem 0.2rem 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#header-navbar{
    background-color: #414141;
}

.nav-link{
    font-family: 'Work Sans';
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 0.7rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    
}
.navbar-toggler:focus{
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
.nav-link:hover{
    color:lightcoral !important;

}
.navbar-toggler-icon{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 162, 134, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") !important;
}
button.navbar-toggler{
    border: 2px solid #FFA286 !important;
    color:rgba(243, 199, 199, 0.52) !important;
    border-radius: 27px;
}
button.navbar-toggler:hover{
    background-color: rgba(235, 193, 193, 0.52) !important;
}
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
    .nav-item{
        background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
        border:#212529 2px solid;} 
}

/* Navbar End */
/* Body Start */
#headerMenu{
    font-family: 'Work Sans';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    font-size: 4rem !important;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
    border:none;
    margin-top: 7rem;
}
#bgimg{
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34)), url(nick-karvounis-Ciqxn7FE4vE-unsplash.jpg);
    filter: blur(1px);
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.box{
    background: #414141;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color:white;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.box:hover .menuhead{
    color: lightcoral;


}
.contentMenu{
    text-indent: 1.8rem;
}

/* Body End */
/* Footer start */
.footer_container{
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color:#212529;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.footer_main{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    height:4rem;
}
/* Footer end */
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Font install -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-default navbar-expand-md justify-content-center align-items-center navbar-dark bg-dark p" id="header-navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- brand navbar -->
            <div class="navbar-brand d-flex me-lg-auto">
                <p id="brandName">Food, LLC</p>
            </div>
            <!-- toogle button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mainNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- navlinks -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
                <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto my-md-0 my-2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#beefMenu">Beef</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#chickenMenu">Chicken</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#sushiMenu">Sushi</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVBAR END -->
    <!-- OUR MENU Start -->
    <div class="container w-100 h-100">
        <p class="display-1 text-uppercase text-center " id="headerMenu">our menu</p>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- <div class="col col-md-4 box">
                <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase py-2 menuhead ">BEEF</h1>
                <p class="px-1 pb-2 contentMenu" id="beefMenu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4 box">
                <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase py-2 menuhead">Chicken</h1>
                <p class="px-1 pb-2 contentMenu" id="chickenMenu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-md-4 box">
                <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase py-2 menuhead">sushi</h1>
                <p class="px-1 pb-2 contentMenu" id="sushiMenu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at.</p>
            </div> -->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
                <div class="box"> <section>
                    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white pt-4 " >Beef</h1>
                <p class="text-white px-4 pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.</p>
                </section></div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <section>
                        <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white pt-4" >Chicken</h1>
                        <p class="text-white px-4 pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.</p>
                    </section>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <section>
                        <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white pt-4">sushi</h1>
                        <p class="text-white px-4 pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <!-- OUR MENU End -->
    <!-- FOOTER Start -->
    <footer class="bg-dark text-center text-lg-start footer_main">
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="text-center text-white p-3">
          Image Credit: Nick Karvounis
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
      </footer>
    <!-- FOOTER End -->
    <!-- Js install -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

**1. Wrap the div that contains your main content.** Consequently, your main content will stop overlapping the footer.

So, change this...

```
<div class="container w-100 h-100">...</div>
```

...into this.

```
<div>
    <div class="container w-100 h-100"></div>
</div>
```

**2. Change the height of the `container`.** That will put the footer to the bottom of the page.

So, add this to your CSS code.

```
.container {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

**3. You can delete a few things.**

You can delete the class `footer_main` from your HTML as it's unnecessary.

You can delete this part of your CSS as it's unnecessary:

```
.footer_container{
    margin-top: auto;
    background-color:#212529;
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
.footer_main{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    height:4rem;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Warnes&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@500;700&display=swap');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(/images/nick-karvounis-Ciqxn7FE4vE-unsplash.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}


/* Navbar Start */

#brandName {
  font-family: 'Warnes', cursive;
  color: #FF511C;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#header-navbar {
  background-color: #414141;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0.7rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: lightcoral !important;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 162, 134, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'") !important;
}

button.navbar-toggler {
  border: 2px solid #FFA286 !important;
  color: rgba(243, 199, 199, 0.52) !important;
  border-radius: 27px;
}

button.navbar-toggler:hover {
  background-color: rgba(235, 193, 193, 0.52) !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .nav-item {
    background-color: rgb(94, 94, 94);
    border: #212529 2px solid;
  }
}


/* Navbar End */


/* Body Start */

#headerMenu {
  font-family: 'Work Sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  font-size: 4rem !important;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
  border: none;
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

#bgimg {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.34)), url(nick-karvounis-Ciqxn7FE4vE-unsplash.jpg);
  filter: blur(1px);
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  background: #414141;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover .menuhead {
  color: lightcoral;
}

.contentMenu {
  text-indent: 1.8rem;
}


/* Add this. */

.container {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Font install -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Restaurant</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAVBAR START -->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-default navbar-expand-md justify-content-center align-items-center navbar-dark bg-dark p" id="header-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- brand navbar -->
      <div class="navbar-brand d-flex me-lg-auto">
        <p id="brandName">Food, LLC</p>
      </div>
      <!-- toogle button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mainNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <!-- navlinks -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto my-md-0 my-2">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#beefMenu">Beef</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#chickenMenu">Chicken</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#sushiMenu">Sushi</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- NAVBAR END -->
  <!-- OUR MENU Start -->
  <div>
    <div class="container w-100 h-100">
      <p class="display-1 text-uppercase text-center " id="headerMenu">our menu</p>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- <div class="col col-md-4 box">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase py-2 menuhead ">BEEF</h1>
                    <p class="px-1 pb-2 contentMenu" id="beefMenu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4 box">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase py-2 menuhead">Chicken</h1>
                    <p class="px-1 pb-2 contentMenu" id="chickenMenu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-md-4 box">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase py-2 menuhead">sushi</h1>
                    <p class="px-1 pb-2 contentMenu" id="sushiMenu">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis at.</p>
                </div> -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12 ">
          <div class="box">
            <section>
              <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white pt-4 ">Beef</h1>
              <p class="text-white px-4 pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi
                tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed
                viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi
                cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.</p>
            </section>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
          <div class="box">
            <section>
              <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white pt-4">Chicken</h1>
              <p class="text-white px-4 pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi
                tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed
                viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi
                cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.</p>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
          <div class="box">
            <section>
              <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white pt-4">sushi</h1>
              <p class="text-white px-4 pb-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Sit amet nulla facilisi morbi
                tempus iaculis. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum nibh. Mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit. Suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed
                viverra tellus. Interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim. Lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi
                cras fermentum odio. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent.</p>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- OUR MENU End -->
  <!-- FOOTER Start -->
  <footer class="bg-dark text-center text-lg-start">
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center text-white p-3">
      Image Credit: Nick Karvounis
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
  <!-- FOOTER End -->
  <!-- Js install -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! So to be clear, the problem of my is not wrapping the content into div so that the footer was collapsed?

Comment: You're welcome. :) After wrapping your main content in a div, it stops overlapping the footer. A little "trick" you can do is to remove this wrapper div and you'll see visually what happens. Then you can also remove `.container {height: auto !important;}` and see what happens if you remove that too. Basically, reverse engineer my solution.